# Li correct positioning

Tags: css, magento

[image]

I need help with my product list. Because of large text in 3 element, 5 element moves down. How to fix it? List items have "first" and "last" classes, also.

Comment: You need to give them a fixed height which is larger than your text.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just add "clear: left" to .first item

Answer (score 0):

Set each product div to a fixed height. That way the items can fill the given space responsively and fill as much horizontal space as possible.

If you were to clear the float on each row, you would be stuck with four products on each row or worse if the parent element becomes smaller than 4 items wide, which would push the last elements down into an ugly new row.

From:
|             |
| X X X X |
|             |
| X X X X |
|             |

To:
|          |
| X X X |
| X       |
|          |
| X X X |
| X       |
|          |